# Add array attributes to implode()

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, implode

I don't know PHP, but I have to work in it. I need add to `$attr['ids']` array with `$gallery_setting`.

```
function the_featured_image_gallery( $atts = array() ) {

    $gallery_setting = get_theme_mod( 'featured_image_gallery' );

    if ( is_array( $gallery_setting ) && ! empty( $gallery_setting ) ) {
        $atts['ids'] = implode( ',', $gallery_setting );

        echo gallery_shortcode( $atts );
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like:

```
echo gallery_shortcode( $atts, array(
  'order'      => 'ASC',
  'size'       => 'full',
  'link'       => 'none'
) );
```

but I know that it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify your question. It's not clear what your problem is...

To try a shot in the dark:

```
function the_featured_image_gallery( $atts = array() ) {

    $gallery_setting = get_theme_mod( 'featured_image_gallery' );

    if ( is_array( $gallery_setting ) && ! empty( $gallery_setting ) ) {
        $atts['ids'] = implode( ',', $gallery_setting );

        $additional_atts = array(
          'order'      => 'ASC',
          'size'       => 'full',
          'link'       => 'none'
        );            
        $atts = array_merge($atts, $additional_atts);

        echo gallery_shortcode( $atts );
    }
}
```